# Custom DataTypes not synching between devices

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I am trying to use the Google Fit API to store custom *dataTypes*.

I am able insert, and retrieve them fine on a single device, but when I log into the same Google account on a different device the data is not there.

I can create and retrieve data from each device but they both keep their own data, and do not sync up thru the cloud.

I have tried using

```
.enableServerQueries()
```

in my *DataReadRequest* builder and still nothing.

Comment: You can use it vis sharable data types. https://developers.google.com/fit/android/data-types#shareable_data_types

Comment: Note in custom data type : https://developers.google.com/fit/android/data-types#custom_data_types

Comment: I read that to mean it's only read by the app as a whole. Meaning your custom datatype is usable by only by your app on any device. Not just the one instance of of the app on the one device that made it. That's a real bummer.

Comment: I guess it's the data source changing since device changed...